# Disable ESlint single-quotes rule only inside one SCSS file

Tags: eslint

How can I disable ESlint single-quotes rule only inside one SCSS file?

I tried:

```
/* eslint-disable quotes  */
/* eslint-disable single-quotes  */
```

But ESlint still complaing about double-quotes in the file.

Comment: What plugin are you using to lint SCSS files? If you are not sure, could you show the error message printed by ESLint?

Comment: Could you find the soultion, If found, can you please share here?